# mysql SET CASE WHEN THEN with AND not expected result

Tags: mysql

Initial mysql table

```
 RowIdPaidusedUnique | TypeOfBookkeepingRecord 
 ---------------------------------------------
     1               |     45
     2               |     45
     3               |     4
```

Query is

```
UPDATE 2_1_paidused 
SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = CASE RowIdPaidusedUnique 
WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ? 
AND TypeOfBookkeepingRecord <> ? 
END;
```

Array is

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 5
[2] => 2
[3] => 5
[4] => 4
)
```

Want to get

Where `RowIdPaidusedUnique` is 1 and TypeOfBookkeepingRecord is not 4, then change `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord` to 5

Where `RowIdPaidusedUnique` is 2 and TypeOfBookkeepingRecord is not 4, then change `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord` to 5

But as result got

```
 RowIdPaidusedUnique | TypeOfBookkeepingRecord 
 ---------------------------------------------
     1               |     5
     2               |     1
     3               |
```

Seems something is incorrect with `AND TypeOfBookkeepingRecord <> ?`

Do I need to change to something like

```
WHEN ? AND TypeOfBookkeepingRecord <> ? THEN ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do it like below using `CASE` statement and put the condition `TypeOfBookkeepingRecord is not 4` in `WHERE`.

See a demo fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c831/1

```
UPDATE table1
SET TypeOfBookkeepingRecord = 
(CASE WHEN RowIdPaidusedUnique = 1 then 5 
 WHEN  RowIdPaidusedUnique = 2 then 1 END)
WHERE TypeOfBookkeepingRecord != 4
```